# How to convert PDF into image using pdfbox 2.0.7

Tags: java, pdfbox

When I try to convert PDF document into image and display into Jframe using pdfbox 2.0.7 and the program  will generate:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory exception
```

Can anybody help me or is there any other PDFbox document viewer rather than image?

Because I have no idea to display PDF rather than converting documents into image and display images into JLabel.

Here is the code... `jf.getSelectedFile()` is file from JFileChooser:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load ( jf.getSelectedFile () );
PDFRenderer d = new PDFRenderer ( doc );
int index = doc.getNumberOfPages ();
for ( int i = 0; i <= index - 1; i ++ ) {
BufferedImage im = d.renderImage ( i , 200 , ImageType.RGB );
ImageIO.write ( im , "jpg" , new File ( "J:\\iTutor Ethiopia\\out put\\image_" + i ) );
```

The code that display image into JLabel is not writen here.

Comment: See https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html

Comment: The main SO question about converting to images https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481535/how-to-convert-pdf-into-image-using-pdfbox-2-0-7 also tells to look at the dependency page.

Comment: @Meshu Any update on this? Has your problem been solved by the links? If yes, then delete your question.

Comment: yes my problem has solved